# Reading data from .txt to an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I'm quite new to c++ and basically what I want to do is retrieve information from a .txt file and add this data into an array. Here's what I've tried:

```
string fileName;
string trainArray[20][3];

cout << "\nPlease enter the full file name: ";
cin >> fileName;
int  spaceCount = 0;

ifstream trainFile (fileName,ios::binary);
if (trainFile.is_open()){              
    char ch;
    while(!trainFile.eof()){
        trainFile.get(ch);
        if(ch==' ')
            spaceCount++;
    }
    spaceCount = spaceCount/2;
    cout <<spaceCount;

    for (int i=0; i<=spaceCount; ++i){                    
        trainFile >> trainArray[i][0];
        trainFile >> trainArray[i][1];
        trainFile >> trainArray[i][2];                   
    }
    trainFile.close();
}
```

This works, as I have checked the folder and a new .txt file is created using the input.

Here's my problem, when I try and retrieve the data from the arrays, it just comes up with a load of blank space! Here's the output code:

```
cout << "\nTHIS IS THE CONTENTS OF THE ROUTE ARRAY: \n" << endl;
for (int i=0;i<spaceCount;i++){
    cout << trainArray[i][0] << " " << trainArray[i][1] << " " << trainArray[i][2] <<endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

Because the data in the txt file is always in this preset format: (word word word) with 3 words a line, therefor having 2 spaces a line. I used a counter to work out how many spaces there are in the document, and then divided this by 2 to determine how many times the output should cycle through. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this but it's been a long day... I was thinking of searching for '\n' instead but would that work for a document with only one row as there wouldn't be one?

So my question, how do I change the code so that it actually receives the data from the .txt file instead of just blank space?

Comment: Well, the correct tool to find out what's source of your error is the debugger, not StackOverflow.

Comment: You read the file until you hit the end of file (the while loop) and then you try to read some more things from the file (the for loop). It should be obvious that isn't going to work. But I really don't know what you want to do instead. Maybe you want to rewind the file back to the beginning in between the two loops? You would also need to clear the error condition you've created in the stream as well. Simpler just to close the file and re-open.

Comment: `while(!trainFile.eof())` almost never works because you have to try to read to see if you got to the end of the file. `while (trainFile.get(ch))` should do all the checking you need.

Comment: Thanks john, i'll give it a try. @user4581301, i tried doing that but it still gave me empty space :/

Comment: Since you're new, I highly recommend searching StackOverflow before posting.  For your issue, try these keywords:  "c++ read file array".